# Python Import Module Not Working

Tags: python-3.x, module

I am very new to Python.

I am in command line and I typed the following:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

Python then starts working inside of command line.

When I type

```
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy('testing')
pyperclip.paste()
```

> 'Hello World!'

is printed.

When I go to the python shell and type

```
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy('testing')
pyperclip.paste()
```

I get an error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'

How can I figure out where command line is looking when I type import pyperclip and where it is looking in the python shell to compare the two?

**Edit #1:**

import sys
sys.path

Seems to be important. I am guessing that when a module is imported, python checks one of those locations.

pyperclip-1.5.7 is now located in one of the paths specified., the "Lib" directory.

pyperclip-1.5.7  looks like this inside of the folder:
[image: Inside pyperclip-1.5.7]

All of the other modules are located as ".py" files just outside of the pyperclip-1.5.7, maybe I need to move some stuff there. I wonder how I can tell python to check inside of this directory...

**Edit #2:**

I went to this location: [https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/how-does-python-find-packages.html](http://How%20does%20python%20find%20packages?)

On the page, the author writes:

> So Python will find any packages that have been installed to those
>   locations.

Let's see if I can add something to the sys.path location that points to the specific package that is inside the pyperclip-1.5.7 directory and if that helps.

Comment: pyperclip doesn't have a `__init__.py file`, so python will not detect the directory as a package. maybe run setup.py? maybe try re-installing it because I tried this and it worked fine

Comment: try the command `python -m pip install pyperclip`3rd-party modules should be in `Lib\site-packages`.

Comment: That's exactly what it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong.

I also noticed that there are several posts all over in various locations of people reading the book

> Automate the Boring Stuff with Python.

that are also struggling with this part.

After running

```
import sys
print('\n'.join(sys.path))
```

I started looking for differences between the output in command line and the output in the python shell. Everything looked extremely similar except in the directory:

> lib/site-packages

I copied and pasted what was in this location, as pointed to in command line, to the location pointing to it in the python shell. I closed/reopened the shell and tried running the `import pyperclip` module, etc again and everything worked like a charm.

Problem is now solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have both python 3 and python 2 as well. The problem I faced was even after successful pyperclip installation it was not working in Python 3.

The solution I got was to move to the directory of installation of Python 2
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
and copied the folders 
pyperclip
 and 
pyperclip-1.7.0-py2.7.egg-info
to the python 3 directory which was in my case
C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages